# android avd where were ringtones, Alarms directory running on kitkat os

Tags: android, ringtone

Version lower than Kitkat, I placed my customized audio files in /mnt/sdcard/Alarms, /mnt/sdcard/Ringtones , /mnt/sdcard/Notifications on the avd. Those directories created by default.

I don't find those directories on avd running kitkat. Ie. avd running using API level 19.

I created them manually and place the audio files there. However when my appl running, those directories disappeared, and /mnt/sdcard became inaccessible.

Where should I place the alarms, ringtones and notification audio file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry did not followup this. Resolved now, basically on the avd, etup->storage->erase sdcard. Restart avd. Then /mnt/sdcard or /storage/sdcard is accessible.